# Run docker with aliased port and access to bash

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to start a docker snapshot and connect to it via bash but also alias its port so I can access it from my local system at localhost:3333, this is what I have:

```
docker run -d -p 3333:3000 -t -i mysnapshot /bin/bash
```

However while it does start the container image it doesn't connect to it via bash

This is the output it generates:

> 3c86ca433d645c6c11315e89bbeaf89f072e2d1fa83213d4c4256c4a1af98322

and this is the dockerfile used to build the image:

> FROM node:10
>
> ## Setting working directory. All the path will be relative to WORKDIR WORKDIR /usr/src/app
>
> ## Installing dependencies COPY package*.json ./ RUN npm install
>
> ## Copying source files COPY . .
>
> ## Building app
>
> ## RUN npm run build
>
> ## Running the app CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

Comment: Please provide the output you got after running `docker run`.

Comment: Can you also provide the `dockerfile` if any.

Comment: whats the output of `docker ps`

Comment: done to your two first requests, docker ps shows the running snapshot

Comment: The command `/bin/bash` runs _instead of_ the command you set in the Dockerfile.  I wouldn't generally worry about getting an interactive shell in a container; just run your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `-d` option in `docker run` command, which will run the container in `detached` mode in the background.

Please check [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) out.

To get into the bash run

```
docker exec -it <conatiner-id> /bin/bash
```

where `<container-id>` can be retrieved from `docker ps` output.

Also as per your `dockerfile` you want `npm start` to be the first process in the container, so while running `docker run` command don't specify `/bin/bash` because it will override the `CMD npm start` mentioned in the dockerfile.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may need to overwrite your entrypoint because last line of your dockerfile mention your start command is `npm start`.

Also, `-d` detached mode is not needed.

Try this one:

```
docker run -it -p 3333:3000 --entrypoint=/bin/bash mysnapshot
```